# Is removing unreachable code always safe?

Tags: c#

Assume I have a tool that automatically removes C# code that is detected by the compiler as unreachable. Is there a situation in which such operation can get me into trouble? Please share interesting cases.

Comment: Such a tool should tell a programmer to fix his code instead of keeping him stoopid and doing it for him.  If it doesn't do that then it is quite a useless tool, removing dead code is the job of the jitter optimizer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the interesting example. Consider a function like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> Fun()
    {
        if (false)
        {
            yield return 0;
        }            
    }
```

The line with `yield` is detected as unreachable. However, removing it will make the program not compilable. `yield` contained in the function gives the compiler information to reorganize the function so that not doing anything just returns the empty collection. With `yield` line removed it looks just like ordinary function with no return while it's required.

As in the comment, the example is contrived, however instead of `false` we could have a constant value from other, generated project etc (i.e. such piece of code wouldn't look so obvious as in this case).

**Edit**:
Note that the `yield` construct is actually very similar to `async/await`. Yet with the latter creators of the language took a different (IMO better) approach that prevents such scenarios. Iterator blocks could be defined in the same way (using some keyword in function signature instead of detecting it from the function body).

Comment: That is probably an advantage :)

Comment: Removing it makes the program non compilable because you can't create an if block with no statement.  This isn't a great example, because the whole concept of making an if(false){} is invalid, it will never run and is useless.

Comment: `yield` isn't special here. You would have the same problem if you removed the return value from any other function.

Comment: @Ryios: the example is contrived, indeed. Note, however that instead of false there could be a const value from another class that is generated etc.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: I think that `yield` is special since normally you would other code paths that return value. May you give an example?

Comment: I should have been more specific. If you remove the only return value from a function like in your example, then it doesn't matter if you use `yield` or not. If the code you remove violates the contract of the function, then it matters. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Let's say you are using a T4 Template to generate some C# that builds in the project.  Let's say it creates a constant variable.  Now let's say the value it generates is either 0, or 1 and your if block checks if the value is > 0.  The code generates a constant with a value of 0.  At such a point I believe the code would be detected unreachable, but should not be removed, because it's possible for the T4 template to generate a constant with a value of 1.

Never really though about that till just now.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: yes, but without yield the only exit point that is unreachable would mean that the function wouldn't compile anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't this code produce "Not all code paths return a value" (compile error) when compiling, no matter what's inside the if (which contents are unreachable) ?

Comment: @Alex No.  Go ahead and try it out for yourself.

Comment: Fair enough. I still feel the example is a bit contrived though.

Comment: I always forget taht `yield` is .. peculiar

Comment: @Ryios: and BTW, you can have an if block with no statement, it is perfectly fine for the compiler.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski That's not quite true.  An `if` block *must* be followed by exactly one statement.  It's simply the case that `{}` is a valid statement.  However `if(false) else {}` isn't valid, because the `if` isn't followed by a statement.

Comment: @Servy: ok, if that's what Ryios had on mind, then I naturally agree. However, I don't feel how it connects with my example, where brackets are not removed.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do this *automatically*, for reasons mentioned in other answers, but I will say here that I'd have a strong bias towards removing unused code over keeping it. After all, tracking obsolete code is what source control is for.

Answer (score 3):

This example is contrived, but this will get flagged for removal (in default `DEBUG` settings) and produce different behaviors when removed.

```
public class Baz { }

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        if (false)
        {
            // Will be flagged as unreachable code
            var baz = new Baz();
        }

        var true_in_debug_false_in_release =
            GetType()
            .GetMethod("Bar")
            .GetMethodBody()
            .LocalVariables
            .Any(x => x.LocalType == typeof(Baz));

        Console.WriteLine(true_in_debug_false_in_release);
    }
}
```

In `Release` mode (with default settings), the "unreachable code" will optimized away and produce the same result as if you deleted the `if` block in `DEBUG` mode.

Unlike the example using `yield`, this code compiles regardless of whether or not the unreachable code is removed.

Answer (score 3):

Further to [Dan Bryant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021156/33080), here's an example of a program whose behaviour *will* be altered by a tool that's smarter than the C# compiler in finding and removing unreachable code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static bool tru = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Destructive();
        while (tru)
        {
            GC.Collect(2);
        }
        GC.KeepAlive(x); // unreachable yet has an effect on program output
    }
}

class Destructive
{
    ~Destructive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Blah");
    }
}
```

The C# compiler does not try very hard to prove that `GC.KeepAlive` is unreachable, so it doesn't eliminate it in this case. As a result, the program loops forever without printing anything.

If a tool proves that it's actually unreachable (fairly easy in this example) and removes it, the program behaviour is changed. It will print "Blah" straight away and then loop forever. So it has become a different program. Try it if you have doubts; just comment out that unreachable line and see the behaviour change.

If `GC.KeepAlive` was there for a reason then this change would, in fact, be unsafe, and will make the program misbehave at some point (probably just crash).

Comment: Servy is right that my answer did not really address the question, since it was about removing code that the compiler detected as unreachable.  I was mistaken in my assumption that the KeepAlive would function regardless of whether it could be proven unreachable.  The above is the case I was alluding to, though, in the follow-up; it doesn't answer the question, but it's potentially interesting information for someone researching this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One rare boundary case is if the unreachable code contains a [GC.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call.  This very rarely comes up (as it is related to particular hacky use cases of unmanaged/managed interop), but if you are interoperating with unmanaged code that requires this, removing it could cause intermittent failures if you're unlucky enough to have GC trigger at just the wrong moment.

---

UPDATE:

I've tested this and I can confirm that Servy is correct; the GC.KeepAlive call does not take effect due to the fact that the compiler proves it can never actually use the reference.  This is not because the method is never executed (the method doesn't have to execute it for it impact the GC behavior), but because the compiler ignores the GC.KeepAlive when it is provably not reachable.

I'm leaving this answer up because it's still interesting for the counter case.  This is a mechanism for breaking a program if you modify your code to make it unreachable, but don't move the GC.KeepAlive to make sure it still keeps the reference alive.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the call to `KeepAlive` is unreachable why would it make a difference if you remove it?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, I haven't tested this case, but the KeepAlive is basically just a directive to the GC as to when it's allowed to collect a variable.  I believe it should extend the lifetime whether the code is reachable or not, as the actual execution of KeepAlive doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: It's a method call, so if it doesn't run it will have no effect.

Comment: @DanBryant The GC is allowed to collect an object as soon as it can prove that it is never accessed again.  The call to `GC.KeepAlive` is merely creating a "usage" of the variable (as far as the GC is concerned) that doesn't actually use it.  If the GC can prove that the `KeepAlive` isn't reachable, then the variable can very well be provably never used again, allowing it to be collected.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, That's not strictly true; you can construct a method where GC.KeepAlive won't execute due to a flag you pass in, but it will still keep the reference alive whether it executes or not.  It's a bit of an unusual method in that sense.  I was wrong, however, in assuming that the compiler would still keep the reference alive when it was provably unreachable.

Comment: @DanBryant What matters is whether the JITter can *prove* that the variable won't be used again.  If it can't prove that it won't be used (a conditional check is something that it couldn't prove either way until it passes) then it won't collect it.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct. Please see @Servy's comment.

Comment: @Servy wait, but that's exactly the point of this answer: the compiler proves it's unreachable, so it removes the KeepAlive, so the _program behaviour is altered in a detrimental way_. [Here is an example](http://pastebin.com/bvJhDfGA): change `while tru` to `while true` and the program will print "Blah", even though `GC.KeepAlive` is as unreachable as before.

Comment: @romkyns Since the `GC.KeepAlive` is removed when it's not reachable, it is not effecting the program, so removing the unreachable `GC.KeepAlive` is **not** affecting the program in any way.

Comment: @Servy we may be talking about different things? My example produces a **different output** based on whether the compiler is able to eliminate the (unreachable, in both cases) GC.KeepAlive or not. Do you disagree with this statement?

Comment: @romkyns Yes, I disagree with that statement, and in addition to that, that's not what the question is about.  The question is whether removing an unreachable statement affects the program.  Since the compiler will remove `KeepAlive` when its reachable, whether its there or you remove it has no effect on the program, so it can indeed be removed without affecting the program.

Comment: @Servy I've posted a full answer that shows exactly that: a case where removing the clearly unreachable KeepAlive has an effect on the program. It's possible we're interpreting the question differently, but anyway.

Comment: I wonder if any of you realize that `GC.KeepAlive()` doesn’t do anything. It’s just an empty method, and it’s not special. It only exists for readability. You might as well write `Console.Write(string.Format("", myObject))` and it would be the same thing.

Comment: @romkyns But you *haven't* demonstrated a case where removing a method alters the program.  Removing an unreachable `KeepAlive` doesn't affect the program.  The `KeepAlive` will have been removed by the compiler if you didn't remove it, so whether you keep it or not it doesn't affect the program.

Comment: @Timwi, One minor point is that the GC.KeepAlive method has a `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attribute, to prevent an inlining optimization from removing the reference to the variable.

Comment: I'm starting to think that when Servy says "unreachable" they mean "detected as unreachable (and therefore removed) by the C# compiler", while romkyns means "actually unreachable, but potentially left in because the compiler might not detect it".